# Does the verb 'prophesy' have a future tense or equivalent?

Tags: verbs, future

I was writing for a paper and was trying to write that a character will say a prophecy later in the story and was going to write "will prophecize" or something (although that is wrong according to every source I have at my disposal). Is there a proper verb change, and if so, is it not commonly used or recognized; if not, is there a reason why?

Also, I wasn't sure if "future tense" was the right phrasing, but I hope my question is still clear.

Comment: You simply need a verb. Look up a dictionary: *prophecy* is **also** a verb. "Say that (a specified thing) will happen in the future: *Jacques was prophesying a bumper harvest.* " http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/prophesy

Comment: However, it seems to me that you expect the verb to be of a different form for what someone is going to do in future (future tense, as you mentioned.) *Will* and *going to* can signify future tense with a verb in the simple present, as you have correctly used. "English does not have a future tense formed by verb inflection..." (WP: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Future_tense )  See more here: http://www.englishpage.com/verbpage/simplefuture.html See also: [ell.se]

Comment: Huh? "This question is **not** about the English language?"

Comment: 'She will prophesy concerning the Second Coming' is (linguistically speaking) just the usual way of casting the action (her prophesying) in the future (as reckoned from the time the announcement is first made). The announcement is either a prophecy or a false prophecy itself. //  'He makes this prophecy in 578 BCE. He will prophesy again in three years time' is an example of a literary device recording sequential events in the past, using non-logical tense to enhance the sense of immediacy.

Answer (score 4):

The word you are looking for is **prophesy**

> OED 1. intr. To speak by (or as by) divine inspiration, or in the name
>   of a deity; to speak as a prophet.
>
> 2. trans. To announce or utter by (or as by) divine inspiration; esp. so to announce (a future event); to predict, to foretell. a.2.a with
>      obj. clause expressing the matter announced.

Though much more obscure, **prophetize** also correct

> OED 1. trans. To prophesy, predict.
>
> 2. intr. To utter predictions; to prophesy.

Comment: Doesn't address the question (on future tense or a usual workaround in a language not possessing one).

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: The question was "is there a proper verb change." I did not intend to provide a guide to using these words in the writer's situation, which was not well explained. And seeing your answer above explaining this uses (without modification) the verb I said was needed, I fail to see what was missing from my answer, aside from explaining that "will" is needed to explain that things happen in the future.

Comment: OP begins: **Is there a future tense of prophecy?**

'I was writing for a paper and was trying to write that a character will say a prophecy later in the story and was going to write "will prophecize" or something.' // You'll notice that I didn't post an 'answer' as I consider the question too basic for this site. An 'answer' that doesn't even address the OP's question 'is there a future tense ...') is far worse.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: I answered the question about what verbs to use in the situation the author asked about. And you *did* post an answer, that was essentially the same as mine (except for adding "will" before the verb), but in a way that you seem to think entitles you to make condescending remarks about those earnest enough to answer the question without considering it beneath them. In future I suggest avoiding questions you consider too basic to answer.

Comment: 'Is there a proper verb change?' does not mean 'Is there a proper verb?'. The whole question (admittedly not well presented) addresses future construction 'future tense' / 'later in the story' / 'will prophecize or something' / 'verb **change**' / 'future tense' [bolding mine]. I've edited the title to what I'm 90+% sure OP intended.  In future I suggest avoiding answering questions that are too basic here (there are other sites dedicated to such basic English; that is not the intended function of ELU).

Comment: @EdwinAshworth You’re being too picky here. This answer indeed answers the question asked.  We’re not here to dwell on Latin verb inflections.

Comment: @tchrist If the question intended is 'What is the verb corresponding to prophecy', as this answer assumes, I'm aghast at your not close-voting.

Answer (score -2):

the verb is prophesise or prophesize and will prophesise/prophesize is perfecly correct.

Comment: If you check the OneLook.com metadictionary, you will find that only Wordnik lists it (and its source is Wiktionary, which anyone can edit). Wiktionary's entry comments "The use of this word is frowned upon by many authorities including the *Columbia Guide to Standard American English*". In other words, it is currently a non-standard usage.

Comment: I stand corrected on etymological grounds although prophesise is used.